# Passing values from one promise to the next

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

A bit new to javascript.
Been dealing with promises, however ran into a problem i dont know how to approach.

How can i pass a value into the next promise resolve?

Here's my code

```
bot.on('ask.add_account_password', (msg) => {
    let username = users[msg.from.id].username;
    let password = msg.text;
    var accounts = require('./inc/account.js');
    accounts.login_account(username,password).then(function(data){
        var account = data.params;
        console.log(account);
        return accounts.store(msg.from.id,username,password,account.followerCount);
    }).then(function(data){
        let caption = "Your account "+account.username+"("+account.fullName+")has been added\n";
        return bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, account.picture, {caption:caption});
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
        add_account(msg,error.name);
    });
});
```

On the line where i create the caption variable, i'm trying to access the account object created in the block before it(var account = data.params) but i get a reference error saying its not defined. Now i can easily bypass this by just sending the entire object into the accounts.store function and have it resolve the object when done, but that just seems like a dirty workaround to a bigger problem. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`account` is `undefined` at second `.then()`, use `data` to reference the `Promise` value `accounts.store` returned from previous `.then()`

```
.then(function(data) {
  // `data` : `accounts.store` returned from previous `.then()`
  let caption = "Your account " + data.username 
                + "(" + data.fullName + ")has been added\n";
  return bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, data.picture, {caption:caption});
})
```

Comment: What makes you think that `store` returns a (promise for) the `account`?

Comment: @Bergi _"What makes you think that store returns a (promise for) the account"_ Not sure what you mean? The gist of the Answer is that if OP needs to access a value from the previous `.then()` the returned value from previous `.then()` is the parameter at subsequent `.then()`. OP needs to make sure they are returning the correct value that they are expecting at subsequent `.then()`

Comment: Yes, but they `return accounts.store(…)` not `account` so this doesn't work that easily.

Comment: @Bergi It was not immediately clear from OP exactly which object OP was expecting to return from previous `.then()`, nor exactly which object properties were expected at chained `.then()`. We had not gotten that far as to precisely what OP was returning or expecting at chained `.then()`. Not sure how your canonical can assist in that particular matter? Though OP will be able to review different possible patterns of accessing `Promise` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create variable (and set it in promise) in main function or you can return this as result of first promise instead of result from function `store`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in an array and use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the arguments to unpack the array.

```
accounts.login_account(username,password).then(function(data){
    var account = data.params;
    console.log(account);
    return [account, accounts.store(msg.from.id,username,password,account.followerCount)];
}).then(function([account, data]){
    let caption = "Your account "+account.username+"("+account.fullName+")has been added\n";
    return bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, account.picture, {caption:caption});
})
```

You don't actually appear to be using `data`, so you could just return account after calling `store`

Comment: The first propose solution is dangerous in context of promises. When function `store` return promise then chain of promises will be broken.

Comment: You would need to use `Promise.all` to make sure all promises in the array get awaited